# Xcode Input File vs Input File list

Tags: xcode11, carthage

I am using Carthage to add the CSVImporter library to my Xcode project. To add the framework to my project, it says to create files named input.xcfilelist and output.xcfilelist. Then, one must add the paths to the needed frameworks to those files. Finally, it says to add the input.xcfilelist to the Input File Lists section and likewise for the output.xcfilelist. I seem to not be able to create distinct files with frameworks as sub-sections of the file. Is it enough to just add the frameworks directly into the input and output file sections?

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding, you can add every single framework into `Input Files` part. You also can create the `InputFile.xcfilelist` and put all your frameworks into the file. There's no difference.

You just create any file change the format to `.xcfilelist` should works.